# Rendering a few simple world space ui images drastically impacts performance

Tags: unity

I was hoping I could render a little world space ui icon over my trees when they have been marked for cutting. However just showing 70-80 world ui images cuts my FPS in half, using up almost 8ms per frame.

How are you supposed to do this in Unity?

This is all I enable when a tree is marked, parented to a world space canvas:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

World space UI shouldn't have had such an impact on performance. in fact, you're supposed to just use a dozen Canvases in a regular 30fps mobile game. I'm guessing your problem is because of *how* you are using it. Maybe take care of the scripts that interact with it? and Unity has a big article about performance tips of using Canvases, one of which is exactly ***not to enable/disable the canvas gameobject, but rather enable/disable just the Canvas Component***.

And then if you're still having issues, maybe try it on a new sample scene? you should have no performance impact if you add 10 empty world canvas to the new sample scene on a low end PC

Comment: They are just static images that never change, update or interact with anything. The only thing I do is enable/disable the Canvas GameObject, would be surprised if that was the reason for the huge performance impact but I can check.

Comment: It may be related to your canvas object being part of the tree gameObject hierarchy. If that is the case, it may lead to a situation where each change on the tree forces its canvas to be recalculated anew. When something in an hierarchy is modified the whole hierarchy is redone and for canvases sometimes that is a bit expensive.

Comment: @Majs your best bet is to check with the new sample scene I told you about. that way you can be sure it's not the Canvas's problem but rather the way you're using it probably. maybe not even directly your code's doing. could be an indirect affect caused by multiple problems. if you want to find out the issue, you'd have to recreate the system step by step, or do Time.time after each suspicious line of the responsible code. I don't think we can help further though, at least not without a source code